# Access: Having trouble with getting average movies per day

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, ms-access, average

I have a database project at my school and I am almost finished. The only thing that I need is average movies per day. I have a watchhistory where you can find the users who have watch a movie. The instrucition is that you filter the people out of the watchhistory who have an average of 2 movies per day.

I wrote the following SQL statement. But every time I get errors. Can someone help me?

SQL:

```
SELECT
    customer_mail_address,
    COUNT(movie_id) AS AantalBekeken,
    COUNT(movie_id) / SUM(GETDATE() -
        (SELECT subscription_start FROM Customer)) AS AveragePerDay
FROM
    Watchhistory
GROUP BY
    customer_mail_address
```

The error:

> Msg 130, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.

I tried something different and this query sums the total movie's per day. Now I need the average of everything and that SQL only shows the cusotmers who are have more than 2 movies per day average.

```
SELECT 
    Count(movie_id) as AantalPerDag, 
    Customer_mail_address, 
    Cast(watchhistory.watch_date as Date) as Date
FROM 
    Watchhistory
GROUP BY 
    customer_mail_address, Cast(watch_date as Date)
```

Comment: I doubt this query is going to do what you really want, even if you fix the syntax errors.  Try editing the question and providing sample data and desired results.

Comment: You should likely look at the AVG() function and HAVING clause.

Comment: I get the error that i cannot perform an aggregat function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquerry, I thought bij myself that this was indeed the right way to get the average per day. But that error is very annoying :p

Comment: @TomH Yeahh iI tried that but the querry needs to get the subscription_start date and the date right now so it can get the average per day when the subscription started.

Comment: I'm not sure on this one, so I'm not posting this as a solution, however I think you need to limit the query, "SELECT subscription_start FROM Customer", to a specific customer. Something like, "SELECT subscription_start FROM Customer where Customer.ID = WatchHistory.CustomerID". Even in this case, however, I don't think this will work because the select is a sub-query and SQL Server doesn't appear to allow this.

Comment: Check out what Clémentine wrote as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it guys. Finally :)

```
SELECT  customer_mail_address, SUM(AveragePerDay) / COUNT(customer_mail_address) AS gemiddelde
FROM            (SELECT DISTINCT customer_mail_address, COUNT(CAST(watch_date AS date)) AS AveragePerDay
                      FROM            dbo.Watchhistory
                      GROUP BY customer_mail_address, CAST(watch_date AS date)) AS d
GROUP BY customer_mail_address
HAVING        (SUM(AveragePerDay) / COUNT(customer_mail_address) >= 2
```

Answer (score 1):

The big problem that I see is that you're trying to use a subquery as if it's a single value. A subquery could potentially return many values, and unless you have only one customer in your system it will do exactly that. You should be `JOIN`ing to the Customer table instead. Hopefully the `JOIN` only returns one customer per row in WatchHistory. If that's not the case then you'll have more work to do there.

```
SELECT
    customer_mail_address,
    COUNT(movie_id) AS AantalBekeken,
    CAST(COUNT(movie_id) AS DECIMAL(10, 4)) / DATEDIFF(dy, C.subscription_start, GETDATE()) AS AveragePerDay
FROM
    WatchHistory WH
INNER JOIN Customer C ON C.customer_id = WH.customer_id  -- I'm guessing at the join criteria here since no table structures were provided
GROUP BY
    C.customer_mail_address,
    C.subscription_start
HAVING
    COUNT(movie_id) / DATEDIFF(dy, C.subscription_start, GETDATE()) <> 2
```

I'm guessing that the criteria isn't **exactly** 2 movies per day, but either less than 2 or more than 2. You'll need to adjust based on that. Also, you'll need to adjust the precision for the average based on what you want.

Comment: It says the following error: **Msg 8121, Level 16, State 1, Line 11
Column 'Customer.subscription_start' is invalid in the HAVING clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.**

Comment: Thanks. I've added it to the `GROUP BY` clause. Since it should be unique with the customer_email_address it shouldn't affect the query otherwise.

Comment: This querry gives me the total movies per date per customer. **SELECT Count(movie_id) as AantalPerDag, Customer_mail_address, Cast(watchhistory.watch_date as Date) as Date
FROM Watchhistory
Group by customer_mail_address, Cast(watch_date as Date)**

Answer (score 0):

What the error message is telling you is that you can't use SUM together with COUNT.

try putting SUM(GETDATE()-(SELECT subscription_start FROM Customer)) as your second aggregate variable, and

try using HAVING & FILTER at the end of your query to select only the users that have count/sum = 2

Comment: then you probably need to do a join on you tables customer and watchhistory in order for the subscription_start field to be directly accessible in the query. I will edit my post..

Answer (score 0):

maybe this is what you need? 
lets join the two tables Watchhistory and Customers

```
select  customer_mail_address, 
COUNT(movie_id) AS AantalBekeken,
COUNT(movie_id) / datediff(Day, GETDATE(),Customer.subscription_start) AS AveragePerDay
from Watchhistory inner join Customer 
on Watchhistory.customer_mail_address = Customer.customer_mail_address
GROUP BY
    customer_mail_address
having AveragePerDay = 2
```

change the last line of code according to what you need (I did not understand if you want it in or out)

Comment: It says that the column "AveragePerDag" is invalid.You have made a custom table name. I don't really know if you can add that in the having statement..

Comment: Did you try changing the having statement with the actual definition? Having count(movie_I'd) / datedif...... >2 ??